# How to call servlet from jsp?

Tags: java

I have my jsp file in the folder WEB-INF/ jsp. and i have my servlet file in the package src/com.apnt.mobilecontacts.StoreContacts .java   so  how to call servlet file from the jsp

Comment: you can import java class in jsp.

Comment: Explain what you mean by _how to call servlet file from the jsp_. How do you think HTTP works?

Comment: Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and then read [Stack overflow help center: "How to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit your jsp page to servlet. For this use`<form>`  tag.

And to redirect use:

```
response.sendRedirect("servleturl")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways but I will suggest few

1.By form action

In the jsp write a form

```
<form action="servlet">
.
.
</form>
```

2.by using sendRedirect()

```
response.sendRedirect(servlet);
```

Comment: @JohnBritto accepting answer is the stackoverflow way of saying thanks